# iPhone view photos - Swiping to any direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, swipe, photos

I want to make an photo gallery in my iPhone app, but with photos in all directions, like a mosaic.

[image]

Is it possible?

Maybe not with a lot of UIImageViews, but just one, and just changing the photos. The problem is: I need a sliding (or something else) effect.

I will be glad if anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it yourself with 2 image views, each with a pan gesture recognizer (because only 2 images can ever be on screen at the same time.

Basically, show the first image view. When a pan is detected, determine its direction. That will tell you which image to load and how I perform the animation.

The animation is as sime as changing the frames of the 2 image views. Add the new image view off screen then animate both of the 'sideways' till the old view is off screen and the new one is positioned. Then you can discard the old one or keep and reuse it for the next gesture.

Comment: Awesome. You know where can I find some animation effects, maybe like Flipboard. Thank you.

Comment: Apple supply a number of animation effects. Or you can apply transforms to the views as you move them into position.